# Freezing intermediate layers in ALBERT

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I want to freeze intermediate sub-layers in ALBERT. Unlike BERT,
ALBERT's encoder looks like this

```
(encoder): AlbertTransformer(
      (embedding_hidden_mapping_in): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=768, bias=True)
      (albert_layer_groups): ModuleList(
        (0): AlbertLayerGroup(
          (albert_layers): ModuleList(
            (0): AlbertLayer(
              (full_layer_layer_norm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              (attention): AlbertAttention(
                (query): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (key): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (value): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (dropout): Dropout(p=0, inplace=False)
                (dense): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=768, bias=True)
                (LayerNorm): LayerNorm((768,), eps=1e-12, elementwise_affine=True)
              )
              (ffn): Linear(in_features=768, out_features=3072, bias=True)
              (ffn_output): Linear(in_features=3072, out_features=768, bias=True)
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
```

So inside the `modulelist`, we can easily choose which sublayers to freeze. But here, we have one module. The documentation says that there are 12 repeating layers. Is there any good way to freeze intermediate layers in ALBERT?

Comment: maybe use `parameters()` and `requires_grad` to freeze intermediate layers.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the config sets `inner_group_num` to 1. It can be modified by the user to obtain required number of modules in ModuleList.

```
config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    model_args.config_name if model_args.config_name else model_args.model_name_or_path,
    num_labels=num_labels,
    finetuning_task=data_args.task_name,
    cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir,
)

config.inner_group_num = 6

model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_args.model_name_or_path,
    config=config,
    cache_dir=model_args.cache_dir,
)
```